# SQL Error in my android project "no such column in table"

Tags: java, android, sql, database

I'm trying to select from my database certain row by column "ID_TABLITSY" by using method "getid" but I get an error "no such column in mytable".

Database class code:

```
public class dbelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "orginizer.db";

private static final int SCHEMA = 2;
static final String TABLE = "mytable";
static final String TABLE_DOM = "table_dom";
static final String TABLE_RAB = "table_rab";

public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
public static final String COLUMN_NOTE = "note";
public static final String COLUMN_DATE = "date";
public static final String ID_TABLITSY = "idtable";

public dbelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, SCHEMA);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "--- onCreate database ---");

    db.execSQL("create table mytable(" + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + COLUMN_NOTE + " TEXT, " + COLUMN_DATE + " TEXT, " + ID_TABLITSY + " INTEGER);");
    db.execSQL("create table table_dom(" + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + COLUMN_NOTE + " TEXT, " + COLUMN_DATE + " TEXT);");
    db.execSQL("create table table_rab(" + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + COLUMN_NOTE + " TEXT, " + COLUMN_DATE + " TEXT);");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_DOM);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_RAB);

    onCreate(db);

}
 public Cursor getid(int ID_TABLITS){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String sqlQuery = "select * from mytable where ID_TABLITSY = " + ID_TABLITS + ";";
    return db.rawQuery(sqlQuery, null);
 }
```

}

and here the way i use this method in the other class

```
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
    Cursor cursor = dbHelper.getid(1);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

        super.onResume();
        db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

        userCursor = db.rawQuery("select * from " + dbelper.TABLE, null);
        String[] headers = new String[]{dbelper.COLUMN_NOTE, dbelper.COLUMN_DATE, dbelper.ID_TABLITSY};
        userAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.two_line_list_item, userCursor, headers, new int[]{android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2}, 0);

        listView.setAdapter(userAdapter);
    }
    cursor.close();
}
```

Error code says that there is no such column but i definitely :

```
    E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such column: ID_TABLITSY
    D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.kp_orginizer, PID: 24010
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity 
    {com.example.kp_orginizer/com.example.kp_orginizer.MainActivity}: 
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: ID_TABLITSY (code 1 
    SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: select * from mytable where ID_TABLITSY = 1;
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4205)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4237)
    at android.app.servertransaction.ResumeActivityItem.execute(ResumeActivityItem.java:52)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:176)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
 Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: ID_TABLITSY (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: select * from mytable where ID_TABLITSY = 1;
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:986)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:593)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:590)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:61)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:46)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1443)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1382)
    at com.example.kp_orginizer.dbelper.getid(dbelper.java:76)
    at com.example.kp_orginizer.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.java:250)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1446)
    at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:7939)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4195)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4237) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.ResumeActivityItem.execute(ResumeActivityItem.java:52) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:176) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ID_TABLITSY` is the name of the variable containing the column's name, not the name of the column:

```java
String sqlQuery = 
    "select * from mytable where " + ID_TABLITSY + " = " + ID_TABLITS + ";";
```

Comment: Thank you wery much! Now then i just have to solve a bunch of other Errors in my code